# Google Sheets Formula Not Working in Excel

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel, excel-online

I have this formula pasted below that works in Google Sheets, but not in Excel. I've looked up possible solutions, but just cannot find what may be the problem with it. The return I get is just the formula or if I break the formula down further I get `#NAME?`

`=UNIQUE(FILTER('Cost of Sale'!A5:E, 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>"N/A", 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!A4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!D4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!G4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!J4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!M4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!P4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!S4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!V4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!Y4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AB4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AE4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AH4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AK4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AN4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AQ4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AT4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AW4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!AZ4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!BC4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!BF4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!BI4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!BL4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!BO4), 'Cost of Sale'!A5:A<>('Materials'!BR4)))`

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Google Sheets and Excel haven't a 100% compatibility actually recent Excel versions aren't 100% compatible with older versions. What Excel version are you using? Have you already reviewed the Excel list of functions for your version?

Comment: The `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions were introduced in Office 365 and do not exist in prior versions of Excel. So if you don't have a cloud subscription, those functions are not available. The further back in versions you go, the less Excel has in common with Google Sheets. (In addition, I will note that even in Google Sheets, your formula could have been written much more succinctly.)

Comment: This is with the Office 365 version. And yeah I figured it definitely could be done more succinctly. I will continue to try to figure out how to do this with Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Excel does not like `A5:A`. `A` needs to be defined. `A5:A1000` will work.